# How to SUM multiple fields with condition

Tags: sql

Here is my table structure

```
id  col1  col2  col3  col4
1       1     1     2     1
```

the thing is, i want to SUM field (col1,col2,col3,col4) but only the value 1.
so based on the record above. the result would be 3 (col1+col2+col4), becauser value from col3 is 2 not 1.

sorry for bad grammar.

Comment: Note that tables have _columns_, not fields.

Comment: @jarlh Fields are essentially what populate the columns within the returned result. https://intellipaat.com/blog/tutorial/sql-tutorial/tables-in-sql/

Comment: @Chobo, in SQL a field is a part of a record data type. For example `select (1, 'a') b from t`, returns one column (b), which has two fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either you mean:

1. You want to calculate a new column on each row which is the sum of columns 1 through 4 if those columns are 1 (which is the same as the count of columns which are 1), or
2. You want to calculate the sum of those columns but only when the row values of those columns are 1

For 1:

```
SELECT id, col1, col2, col3, col4
, CASE WHEN col1 = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
  + CASE WHEN col2 = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
  + CASE WHEN col3 = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
  + CASE WHEN col4 = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
AS row_count_of_ones
FROM table_name;
```

For 2:

```
SELECT SUM(
    CASE WHEN col1 = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
  + CASE WHEN col2 = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
  + CASE WHEN col3 = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
  + CASE WHEN col4 = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
     ) AS count_of_ones
FROM table_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

If i undestood it correctly, this should do what you want (note that you have to change the column_name and table_name to make this work properly, since you didn't posted the names):

```
SELECT SUM(column_name)
FROM table_name
WHERE column_name = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    SUM(
        CASE WHEN Col1 = 1 THEN Col1  ELSE 0 END
        + CASE WHEN Col2 = 1 THEN Col2 ELSE 0 END
        + CASE WHEN Col3 = 1 THEN Col3 ELSE 0 END
        + CASE WHEN Col4 = 1 THEN Col4 ELSE 0 END
        ) as RowTotal
FROM
    [MyTable]
```

Comment: [A code-only answer is not high quality](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers). While this code may be useful, you can improve it by saying why it works, how it works, when it should be used, and what its limitations are. Please [edit] your answer to include explanation and link to relevant documentation.